# CWRU Bearing fault

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, dataset, machine-learning-model

I am new to ML. I have been asked to use a pre-trained GRU model for detecting a bearing fault in CWRU. is pre-trained model another name for transfer learned model?

Comment: What does CWRU stand for?? How is it related to the question?

Comment: I am using the case western reserve university dataset cwru for bearing fault that's why

Answer (score 0):

Fine-tuning a pre-trained model is indeed transfer learning.